# Choosing function over another function Clojure

Tags: design-patterns, clojure, code-reuse

I have set of function like these,

```
(defn nmf-kernel [a b])
(defn lin-kernel [a b])
(defn log-kernel [a b])
```

Then another set of initialization function like these,

```
(defn fill-random 
  ([a b] "filling matrix random")
  ([a b c] "filling matrix random with another setting parameter"))
```

Ok, and i have a scenario :

```
(defn scenario 
   [kernel a b c d e f g]
   (let [init-fn (if (= kernel nmf-kernel)
                     (fill-random a b)
                     (fill-random a b c))))
```

Question : how can i choose a function over another function idiomatically ? because when i'm using `(if (= kernel nmf-kernel))` it feels this method is not elegant. And, how can i design this scenario, when i have 10 kernel function and 10 ways to filling the matrix ?

PS : i have same problem in kernel function creation, but maybe the answer for the kernel function is using protocol in Clojure.

Comment: I think you might be looking for multi methods.

Comment: What is `eval-kernel`? I get the impression that your `kernel` parameter to `scenario` is a function itself that you want to evaluate? Or is it just a flag (e.g. a symbol or keyword)? If the latter using `=` for comparison to the function `nmf-kernel` will always fail.

Comment: @Vanessa hmm, ok i'll check defmulti to design those method, thanks for helping :D 

eval-kernel is never exist, i already edit the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read you correctly, you have a number of possible *kernel function*s, and - for each of these - a corresponding *initialization function*.

Functions are values, so you can make a map:

```
(def kernel->initialization {nmf-kernel (fn do-something [& _] "Hello")
                             lin-kernel (fn do-something-else [& _] "world!")
                             ; ...
                             })
```

... which you can use to choose the appropriate initialization:

```
((kernel->initialization nmf-kernel) "blah" "blah" "blah")
; => "Hello"
```

Normally, you'd use a [`case` form](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/latest/clj/clojure.core/case/) for this sort of thing. But it doesn't work - functions are not the *compile-time* literals that `case` needs for its keys.

---

If your criteria for choosing an initialization function are likely to get more complicated, multi-methods are the way to go. But they're a bit heavy for just choosing on one function on the basis of another.

Comment: phew, thanks for the help. + 1 for the mapping technique, i agree with the multimethod is being so heavy when i want to choose a certain function.